# Deleting dynamic memory pointed by static pointer

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, kernel, device-driver

I have the following structure (simplified):

```
class myType
{
    static char* data;
    //more private data here
public:
    //public interface here
};
```

`data` is a resource shared between all the instances of `myType` and it points to a dynamically allocated memory (allocated by one of the instances upon initialization).

So far so good. The problem arises when I need to free the memory pointed by `data`. Reference counting isn't a solution here because it's a valid and possible situation to not have a single instance of `myType` at some point of execution - and later a new instance can be created - thus the `data` must persist.

I need to free that memory upon driver unload but unload isn't related to the actual destruction of `myType` objects, thus I'm forced to free the `data` manually. This would be acceptable but `data` is (and should be) `private` and inaccessible from the unload handler. Sure, I can create a `static` and `public` `destroy` function inside `myType` but that doesn't seem right - after all I didn't need the `public` initializer, so why would I need one to free the memory? That data shouldn't be accessible from outside `myType` instances.

I'll appreciate any insights on the subject.

Comment: Did you tried the pattern singleton?

Comment: @Jiwan how do you see a Singleton solving this if he wants to allow the memory to eventually be freed (since if he doesn't care about freeing the memory, he has no issue in the first place)? In a sense the `static char *data` is already a Singleton -- just of that buffer rather than the entire object.

Comment: @mah Take a look at Grizzly's second solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your code I would prefer one of two options:

1. Have a static public `destroyMetadata` method, which needs to be called if any instances have been created during the execution. Personally I don't see anything particularry bad with having a method to destroy implicitely created data. The problem with this approach is just that it is a manual approach and therefore somewhat bugprone
2. Create a (singleton) Unload-Handler, where you can register callbacks to be executed on cleanup. Then you can make your `destroyMetadata` a private static method and register it with the handler when `data` is first created. This is a bit more effort, but yields a cleaner design overall.

Which of these two is right for you depends on how complex your cleanup is likely to become. If you have dozens of classes with custom cleanup the second option seems preferable since it yields better encapsulation and cleaner code overall. However if this the only part of your code, where you need such cleanup it is a bit overkill to write such a generalized handler (YAGNI), so the first approach, while conceptually messier, looks much better in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks, you've convinced me - I'll go for option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Not needing a public initializer to allocate it is irrelevant with regards to freeing it -- it's trivial to allocate it on first use because you're running code that knows it needs to be there (if (data==NULL) data=new...), but if this doesn't make sense in your destructor then a public deallocator may be required if you want to ensure that the memory is returned.

Another possibility (if it makes sense in your case) is a reference count incremented in your constructor and decremented in your destructor but when the count reaches zero, don't immediately deallocate. Instead, at that time you can set a timer to deallocate after a certain "cooling down" period. If the constructor (or other code that lazily allocates the memory) is called before this timer fires, you cancel the timer instead of reallocate, but if the timer fires, it deallocates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why a `public static` destroy function wouldn't seem right. As you argue yourself, there is no relationship between the required moment of destruction, and the lifetime of the object and its instances itself. As such you are putting the responsibility for the timely destruction with an outside entity, which then logically needs to be able to access it. The `public static` approach makes most sense in that case. It's sort of a thin garbage collector that way.

I think the underlying architecture is flawed in that it requires you to make this decision, and the data container should be a separate properly reference counted class with proper lifecycle control and a real garbage collector, but that depends on the rest of the code. The solution described might very well be best.

Comment: Unfortunately, the architecture isn't in my hands, it's imposed by the environment